# translate with (a word) or translate as (a word)?

Tags: prepositions

> This can be translated **with** words like "any" or "some"
>
> This can be translated **as** "any" or "some"

Are both sentences correct ?

Comment: Could you explain it further? It's unclear, I'm afraid.

Comment: well , my whole life i've used "as" with the verb "to translate" but just yesterday i came across the first sentence above . although it could have a slightly different meaning to it ,it made perfect sense to me , so now i question whether or not using "as" is right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, and I think in general they mean pretty much the same thing.

Using "as" implies that there is a direct (1-to-1) correlation between the phrase being translated and the equivalent given with "as" (you can just replace one with the other).  Using "with" might, in some cases, suggest that those words are part of the translation but are possibly not the whole result (they would need to be combined with other words to make something that fully means the same thing).